# Undefined variable - While api fetch | Axios | Props

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

My main component - Home

A really simple component, I pass the fetch variable to another component.

```
<template>
      <Page actionBarHidden="true">
        <ComponentA :api="api.somevariable"></ComponentA>
      </Page>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    import ComponentA from "./ComponentA.vue";
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          isLoading: false,
          result: []
        };
      },
       components: {
        ComponentA,
      },
       created() {
        this.loadData();
      },
       methods: {
           async loadData() {
              let self = this;

              console.log("fetch");

              self.isLoading = true;
              const { data } = await Endpoints.get();
              self.isLoading = false;
              self.api = data;
              console.log(data); // returns the data as intended
            }
       }
    </script>
```

The componentA is also simple

```
<template>
  <Label :text="somevariable"></Label>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      somevariable: 0
    };
  },
  props: {
    api: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
     this.somevariable = this.api;
  }
};
</script>
```

The error I am getting is  [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "api". Expected Number with value NaN, got Undefined in the componentA, after some quoting and requoting of console.logs it actually picks up the value. I am not sure why is that, is my approach wrong? This frustrates me, can't figure it out for some hours already.

Comment: from what i can tell in the parent component there is no api.somevariable until the async request complete

Comment: I feel like its trying to get the variable before it actually gets fetched.. perhaps, if so how to fix that

Comment: maybe make created async, or dont render componentA until you have the data

Comment: well still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api` isn't defined in the `data` for the first component, so it won't be reactive. That should be giving you a warning message in the console.

```js
data () {
  return {
    api: null,
    isLoading: false,
    result: []
  };
}
```

The second problem is that when the component first renders it won't yet have loaded `api` from the server. Using `await` won't help with this, rendering the template will happen before the asynchronous request has completed.

Given the way `componentA` is currently written it won't be able to cope with `api` being missing when it is first created. So you'll need to use a `v-if` to defer creation until that data is available:

```html
<ComponentA v-if="api" :api="api.somevariable"></ComponentA>
```

Without the `v-if` check it'll just be passing the initial value of `api`, which in your original code is `undefined`. That is what caused the warning mentioned in the question.

When you talk about *'quoting and requoting of console.logs'*, I would assume that those changes are just triggering hot reloading, which could easily cause components to re-render with the new data. That wouldn't happen otherwise because of the lack of reactivity caused by `api` not being included in the original `data`.

Comment: Its working actually, would never think about that thank you ;)